# Pulling balls out of a box

Tags: probability, reference-request

A box has $b$ blue balls and $r$ red balls. We pull the balls without returning them. What is the probability that the $k$th pull is the first red ball and what is the probability that the last ball is red?

Also: do you know a site which fully explains these kinds of problems and all the variation you can have?

Comment: You might find it useful to look at the [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

**Revised answer**

Part 2 is easy, $\dfrac {r}{r+b}$, because last being red is the same as 1st being red by symmetry.

For part 1, let n = b+r, then if  ball # k is the 1st red, we have (n-k) balls left of which r-1 are red,

thus Pr = ${n-k\choose r-1}/{n \choose r}$

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first question:

$\left(\prod\limits_{n=0}^{k-2}\dfrac{b-n}{b+r-n}\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{r}{b+r-(k-1)}\right)$

Comment: Could you maybe add some explanation?

Comment: @TonyStrong: Choose $1$ blue ball at a time, until you've picked $k-1$ blue balls, then choose $1$ red ball.

Comment: And what is the probability that the last one is red?

Comment: @TonyStrong: I was answering only the first question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be just $\dfrac {\binom b{k-1}\binom r1}{\binom {b+r}k}$?

Comment: @hypergeometric: I don't know, but your suggestion is possibly equivalent to my answer. See the second comment above for a description.

Answer (score 0):

The last one is just
$\frac{r}{\left(r+b\right)}$ , no?

And as I commented "Any n'th ball has the red odds I showed above. Last doesn't change the odds" therefore this is the odds for kth ball as well.

Comment: I think it does

Comment: Of, course the first part is the tough one.

Comment: Matter of perspective. I actually got confused on the second part for a brief moment...

Comment: I think the second one is the tough one...

Comment: @barakmanos but what is the answer to the second one?

Comment: Any n'th ball has the red odds I showed above. *Last* doesn't change the odds.

Comment: @TonyStrong: $\frac{\binom{r}{1}\cdot(b+r-1)!}{(b+r)!}=\frac{r}{b+r}$, which is equal to the answer above.

Comment: Yanga - of course it's an answer. His question contained 2 parts, I answered the second.  I have no question for the author.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I'm sorry I over looked that.

Comment: No worries. My syntax does look like a question more than "here's the answer!" We're good.